# How to get accurate event's systemtime via `Get-WinEvent` and DateCreated event's property?

Tags: windows, powershell, get-winevent

I'm writing a script that has to export events to a CSV file. I want to add rows with accurate system time. What I don't get is how to extract the `SystemTime` property of `TimeCreated`. I.e. this one:

```
 TimeCreated 
   [SystemTime]  2016-10-25T20:04:47.824727500Z
```

Here is a sample of the current output:

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-WinEvent -LogName Application -MaxEvents 10 | Select-Object TimeCreated

TimeCreated
-----------
25.10.2016 23:04:47
25.10.2016 23:04:47
25.10.2016 23:04:17
25.10.2016 23:04:17
25.10.2016 23:04:17
25.10.2016 23:04:17
25.10.2016 23:04:16
25.10.2016 23:04:16
25.10.2016 23:04:16
25.10.2016 23:00:15
```

**Update**

I can add `-ExpandProperty TimeCreated`, but this results in adding extra columns such as `Day, DayOfWeek, DayOfYear, Hour, Kind, Milliseconds, Minute, Month, Second, Ticks, TimeOfDay` and it does not seem like `-ExcludeProperty` works for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do yo mean by "get the `SystemTime` property"? The `TimeCreated` field of eventlog entries contains [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) values, which don't have any such property. If you need the values in a particular [format](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kathykam/2006/09/29/net-format-string-102-datetime-format-string/) you can apply that format via a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Application -MaxEvents 10 |
  Select-Object @{n='TimeCreated';e={
    $_.TimeCreated.ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffZ')
  }}
```

Comment: You beat me while I was expanding on his request for _precise time_ (I assumed to be the milliseconds) on the **Application Log**, which I don't think is feasible.  Good answer though.

Comment: By `SystemTime` I mean the property I can see in Event Viewer and the one I can get via Xpath search.

Answer (score 2):

One caveat to this answer:

This **particular** event log (Application) doesn't record partial seconds.  ie: You would always receive `000000` after the `.` for the seconds.  So, your *precise time* would need to effectively be the singular second.

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Application -MaxEvents 10 | Select-Object -Expand TimeCreated | ForEach-Object { 
    $date = [DateTime]$_
    $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffff")
}
```

Further, if you take a look at the event logs (manually), you'll see that they don't offer any more precision, **on the Application logs**, to the exact time of an entry either.  They seem to just rely on HH:MM:SS for that log.

Now.. the **Security** log, for example, has more precision, so try:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -MaxEvents 10 | Select-Object -Expand TimeCreated | ForEach-Object { $date = [DateTime]$_; $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffff"); }
```

... and you get your milliseconds reported as you wanted!

So that was a two part answer, since your requested logs (Application) does not contain milliseconds tracked.

EDIT: Note that I did NOT do UTC time conversion, as in Ansgar Weicher's answer above.  I left it as system local time.  Hence, removed the 'Z' from the `ToString` formatter.